# Reducing number of breaks to one between two img tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to reduce any more than one `<br>` or `<br/>` tags between two images to only one. It needs to be liberal enough to encounter any kind of attribute info in the images, any kind of whitespace between any of the elements and the two forms of breaks.  Please note, I do not want to affect `<br/>` tags preceeding or trailing `<img>` tags, only those between two images.

This is what I'm using:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]*>)+\s*?(<br\/?>\s*?)+\s*?(<img[^>]*>)+/is','$1<br/>$3',$content);
```

Here's an example

```
    ...
    Some text here.<br>
    <br><img src="http://www.domain.tld/image1.jpg"><br>
    <img src="http://www.domain.tld/image2.jpg"><br><br/>
    <img src="http://www.domain.tld/image3.jpg">
</div>
```

The pattern should only replace the 2 x `<br>` tags between image2 and image3.

I don't know why my pattern isn't working, can you see what I'm not?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**
FYI, I have no control over the original source material in $content.

Comment: Can you tell us what isn't working? Does the regular expression fail to compile? Does it produce wrong output (if so, please give us the output)?

Comment: do not use `<br>`. Valid tag is `<br/>`.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com, please see the FYI where I point out that I have no control over the incomming content, you'll also notice that my replacement string uses the correct format.

Comment: @TimBellis I've selected a working fix, but the symptoms were that  it was either only catching the first result, or none at all, at least as far as my limited test case was concerned.  I also believe that the root cause was explained by Asad later as overlapping matches, albeit his solution didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
preg_replace('/(<img[^>]*>\s*)(<br\s*\/?>(\s*))*(?=<img)/si', '\\1<br/>\\3', $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is an overlap between the first match, which consists of the first two `img` tags, and the next potential match (the last two). Try using this regex instead:

```
(<img[^>]*>)+\s*?(<br\/?>\s*?){2,}\s*?(<img[^>]*>)+
```

See it here: http://rubular.com/r/89UGSRaWOX

To understand the problem more clearly, consider the analogous case of matching the string `aaaa` against the regex `aa`. There are 3 possible matches here:

1. **aa** aa
2. a **aa** a
3. aa **aa**

However, because the second one is an overlap, the only matches found are:

1. **aa** aa
2. aa **aa**

See it here: http://rubular.com/r/DwfGodT08R

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work, although I appreciate your insights into the overlapping matches!

Comment: It does indeed, and I appreciate the linked example.  I tried it in practice where it's applied to dozens of variations and it was only partially working.  I'm not sure what the reason.

Comment: @oucil With other examples you're right this isn't stable, because it is still possible for matches to overlap each other. A general purpose solution is to use a lookahead, which is what Narf has suggested.